# WordPress meta keys order by descending on numbers is not working properly

Tags: wordpress

I'm using this query to fetch the meta keys from db in descending order

```
$your_user_search = new WP_User_Query( array(
            'meta_key' => 'survey_points' , 
            'orderby' => 'survey_points',
            'order' => 'DESC'
            ));
```

But it returns 2,2,1,-30,-1 and it should return 2,2,1,-1,-30.
Looks like its not considering the negative numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes indeed - you'll need to specify that your custom value is numeric: (from the [WP_User_Query documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters))

```
$your_user_search = new WP_User_Query( array(
    'meta_value' => 'survey_points' , 
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', // <-------
    'order' => 'DESC'
));
```

Hope this helps!